# python win32api LoadLibrary path is invalid

Tags: python, winapi

I'm trying to install rpy2, but my problem boils down to something pretty specific.

If I run the following code, I get confirmation that the dll exists but I get an error.

```
import win32api
import os
Rlib = "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.1.1\\bin\\x64\\R.dll"
print Rlib
print os.path.exists(Rlib)
win32api.LoadLibrary(Rlib)
```

Output

```
C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.1\bin\x64\R.dll
True
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-8c5f82c0f2ef> in <module>()
      4 print Rlib
      5 print os.path.exists(Rlib)
----> 6 win32api.LoadLibrary(Rlib)

error: (161, 'LoadLibrary', 'The specified path is invalid.')
```

What is going wrong?

---

More information:

I tried to load another library and it worked fine.
I copied another dll to the same directory and changed the Rlib string to specify the new library.  It worked fine.  There is something wrong with the R.dll library that's preventing me from loading it.

Comment: You may be passing a narrow string to the wide-char version of the `LoadLibrary` function, or vice-versa. Also, if you're running a 32-bit process on 64-bit Windows you could be running into folder redirection.

Comment: Also, assuming you're talking about [this rpy2](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/), why are you trying to manually load the DLL instead of simply importing the Python module (`import rpy2`)?

Comment: @AndrewMedico I did many searches in regards to rpy2 and the win32api error.  What I was getting was disparate questions and answers.  I dug thought the rpy2 code and narrowed it down to what was going on.  I thought this would facilitate this process.